# Adam Schiff’s immunity from treason

Tags: diplomatic-immunity, treason

I’ve just read hundreds of page’s finally released of the House Intel committee & shocked to learn Adam’s claim there was sufficient evidence, compelling evidence, substantive evidence Trump & his campaign colluded with Russia to win the election. All 53 witnesses   Said their WAS NO EVIDENCE, we are not in possession of any evidence, I never saw any evidence, none I ever saw, including Sally Yates, Valerie Hewitt, etc. I read interviews of the Ukraine witnesses & their texts & phone calls to each other & found disturbing calls. Sondland told vindman he’d ask that “no one record or transcribe” the phone call??? My eyes are blurred from reading & there are thousands of pages. ADAM SCHIFF LIED IN CONGRESS ABOUT EVERYTHING IN AN ATTEMPT TO GET TRUMP OUT OF OFFICE. HE WENT ON THE NEWS CHANNELS NOT JUST IN CONGRESS & LIED. HIS LIES WITH THE AID OF OTHERS ALSO LYING GOT TRUMP IMPEACHED. WHY WOULD HIS IMMUNITY ON THE HOUSE FLOOR, if evidence proved his knowingly purposefully lies, impeached a President PROTECT HIM FROM TREASON? As I read others comments it appears that debate law created for this purpose

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because rant.

Answer (score 4):

Schiff is not immune from treason - he has not committed treason.

Treason, under US law:

> Whoever, owing allegiance to the United States, levies war against
>   them or adheres to their enemies, giving them aid and comfort within
>   the United States or elsewhere, is guilty of treason and shall suffer
>   death, or shall be imprisoned not less than five years and fined under
>   this title but not less than $10,000; and shall be incapable of
>   holding any office under the United States.

Even if the circumstances were as you claim, Schiff has not committed treason.